# React antd design select inside a table

Tags: reactjs, antd

I can't get the selected value to be populated and the header for this column in antd table.

In the database Index=AccountNumber , keyword value = 102 which is Account Number. The initial load is not being set. Account number is in the dropdown list of available values but not being set. Its blank when the page loads initially

[image]

Page Loads like this with no selected value for the lookup.
[image]

I want it like this where it is hardcoded value to "Account Number" for test reasons. In reality I want it to be actually populated like a lookup  where keyvalue 102=Account number.

[image]

This is a select dropdown inside a table. The table has 2 columns.
[image]
Datasource for the table is selecteIndexTypeKeyTypes which is a IEnumerable of this class
[image]

Datasource for the dropdown is IEnumerable of this class
[image]

Updated:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value` property passed into the `Select` component is meant to be the corresponding `value` property of the desired `Option` child. Not simply a text value. Change your code to something like this:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
       selectValue: "initial-value",
       ...
   };
}

...
<Select
  value={desKeywordTypeList.length ? (desKeywordTypeList.find(r => /account\snumber/i.test(r.keywordTypeName)) || {}).keywordTypeId : this.state.selectValue}
  onChange={...}>
   {
      desKeywordTypeList.length ? desKeywordTypeList.map(record => (
      <Option key={record.keywordTypeID} value={record.keywordTypeID}>
        {record.keywordTypeName} ({record.keywordTypeID})
      </Option>
      :
      <Option value={this.state.selectValue} key={this.state.selectValue} >Account Number</Option>
   }
</Select>
```

Comment: How can I hardcode the value or value="initial-value"? This is loaded from Database. Currently it is record.keywordTypeId? Can you suggest any codepen please. This value changes for each table row.

Comment: OK, I see. I can't really make a useful codepen out of this as it depends on your data being fetched. I have edited my answer, though

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got my screen to look like its supposed to be. Updated the question

Answer (score 1):

maybe work with defaultValue or initialValue property

```js
<Select defaultValue={...} mode="multiple" placeholder="Assign roles for this user">
    <Select.Option value="role_admin">Administrator</Select.Option>
    <Select.Option value="role_seller">Seller</Select.Option>
    <Select.Option value="role_customer">Customer</Select.Option>
  </Select>
```

```js
{getFieldDecorator('roleList', {
  initialValue: user.roleList || [],
  rules: [
    { required: false, message: 'Assign roles for this user', type: 'array' },
  ],
})(
  <Select mode="multiple" placeholder="Assign roles for this user">
    <Select.Option value="role_admin">Administrator</Select.Option>
    <Select.Option value="role_seller">Seller</Select.Option>
    <Select.Option value="role_customer">Customer</Select.Option>
  </Select>
)}
```